# Sequentially Numbered Labels in MS Word titles

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm using Microsoft Word (Office Home Business 2019) and I would like to give a label in the form of **XYYY** where **X** is a fixed letter and *YYY* is a number that sequentially increase.

These labels must appear only on titles (I'm currently using Title 4)

Example:

##### A001 - This is a title

this is a text

##### A002 - This is another title

this is another text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the "Home" tab, go to the "Paragraph" section, click on "Multilevel List" and select "Define New Multilevel List"

[image]

2. Open the "More" options

[image]

3. For the number formatting, enter the character in front of the automatic number (and if desired the space and dash after the number). For the number style, select the 3-digit number with leading zeros. If you want, you can additionally select a style which will automatically be applied to your list entries.

[image]

4. Confirm everything with "OK" and the new list should already automatically start. If not, then you will find it in the "Multilevel List" dropdown.

Comment: I haven't the "More Options"

Comment: @NicoCaldo can you please paste a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

### You can use [SEQ Fields](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/numbering.htm#Sequence_Fields) for this as well as potentially Mail Merge for the text

`A{ SEQ Label \# 000 }` your text

The link in the title is to my writing on this SEQuence field. Here is a [link to the Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/field-codes-seq-sequence-field-062a387b-dfc9-4ef8-8235-29ee113d59be). You cannot simply type a field, Word needs to insert the `{}` braces. Here is [my article on dealing with Fields](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/dealing-with-fields-in-microsoft-word/e1bdddad-5a51-4327-837c-c3786c16a501) for more on that.

> **Syntax**
>
> When you view the Seq field in your document, the syntax looks like
> this:
>
> ```
> { SEQ Identifier [Bookmark ] [Switches ] }
> ```
>
> Note:  A field code tells the field what to show. Field results are
> what’s shown in the document after having evaluated the field code. To
> toggle between viewing the field code and the field code results,
> press Alt+F9.
>
> **Identifier**
>
> The name you assign to a series of items to number. The name must
> start with a letter and is limited to 40 characters (letters, numbers,
> and underscores). For example, the name for a series of tables might
> be "tables."

In my example above the Identifier would be "label."

The "# 000" is a switch telling it to always give three digits with leading zeros if needed. More switches specific to the field are in the Microsoft documentation page, but I do not think you will need them. Here is a link to [Word MVP Graham Mayor's page going into detail on field switches](http://www.gmayor.com/formatting_word_fields.htm).

Once you have the field, you can simply copy it and paste into each label and add your text.

### MailMerge

Word's MailMerge feature *could* be used to insert your text from an Excel sheet or some other data source. This would not be required but may make it easier.

Here is a link to the [support page on MailMerge from an Excel workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mail-merge-using-an-excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3). Here is a [Microsoft video on creating labels in Mailmerge](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/print-labels-for-your-mailing-list-276a2cd1-74d2-43d0-ab5a-b90460358ad5).

You would prepare your label as something like:

`A{ SEQ Label \# 000 } { MergeField MyText }`

MyText would be the title of a column in your data source and the merge function would create the labels for you.